# Warnings from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, debugging

Is there any way to view warnings from parsing XAML? Either from runtime or from design time. Is there any way to output them somewhere?

Consider the following example (taken from [WPF 4.5 Unleashed book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672336979) by [Adam Nathan](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/)):

```xml
<ListBox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" DisplayMemberPath="DayOfWeek">
  <Button>Button</Button>
  <Expander Header="Expander"/>
  <sys:DateTime>1/1/2016</sys:DateTime>
  <sys:DateTime>1/2/2016</sys:DateTime>
  <sys:DateTime>1/3/2016</sys:DateTime>
</ListBox>
```

You can note that neither `Button` nor `Expader` have `DayOfWeek` property so there is an empty string displayed for those. Is there any message saying: `Button does not contain DayOfWeek property` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see a BindingExpression path error for each binding that fails in the Output window in Visual Studio when you debug your application (at runtime) provided that you haven't turned off data binding warnings under Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window->WPF Trace Settings.

The bindings are resolved at runtime so you won't see any errors at design or compile time.

Comment: Indeed it is! `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DayOfWeek' property not found on 'object' ''Button' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DayOfWeek; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`. But the place to put them is ridiculous, Output window is even hidden by default while in debug mode...